# .Net core 2.0 console app as a windows service

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to set up a .Net Core Console application as a service. Using .Net standard I usually make use of Topshelf but this does not seem to support .Net Core.

Since Topshelf is not an option what can I do to run the the .Net Core Console application as a Windows service?

I have come access https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService, is this a viable substitute for a production environment?

Comment: When you're targeting a windows service, it is somewhat artificial to worry about .NET Core; why not target .NET and use the inbuilt .NET service support?

Comment: totally offtopic, but on linux i write a console app in .net core and use immortal (https://immortal.run/) to supervise it

Comment: Console apps on linux are fine, in windows the program needs to connect to the service manager through some native API calls. We're running self-contained deployments on customer sites as minimally invasive deployments without IIS config this way (see answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Use the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/) which brings back `ServiceBase` and related APIs to .NET Core, so TopShelf may work out of the box. (the pack is in RC at the time of writing with scheduled stable release about a week away)
2. [TopShelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) now supports .NET Core, based on the compatibility pack / windows compatibility for newer .NET Core versions.
3. https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService seems to work for a lot of users so I suggest giving it a try.
4. The library in (3) is a nice API around [DasMulli.Win32.ServiceUtils](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service) which I wrote for our company to be able to deploy self-contained .NET Core Applications in production. So far we haven't had any problems.
5. Other service hosts which abstract the windows service infrastructure and run arbitrary programs - such as the [Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc/). Note that this may not give good ways to gracefully shut down in reaction to a Stop command.

Comment: Thanks, will await the stable release mentioned in 1

Comment: You can already go ahead using the 2.1.0 RTM early access https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/2.1.0-Early-Access-Downloads

Comment: Update: Topshelf now supports core.

Answer (score 2):

In .net core you do not have the option to run as Service. However, if you containerize your console application you can deploy the container anywhere and it is just the same as running as a service. From .NET Core 2.1 on you are able to use the Host and HostBuilder to manage DI, Logging, Graceful shut down, etc in you console app. Have a look at:

[Hosting services in .NET Core console application](https://thinkrethink.net/2018/08/02/hostbuilder-ihost-ihostedserice-console-application/)

Answer (score 0):

At our company we use [Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc/%22Non-Sucking%20Service%20Manager%22) which so far I had no problems with, you might want to have a look.